# I try to make a function that hides the payment method title and subtitle when the cart is 0,- while using a coupon by ID

Tags: wordpress, function

I try to make a function that adds hides the payment method title when the cart total is 0,- with the use of a coupon. Can you all help me please!!

This is what I tried already.

```
// Add title and subtitle for payment form.
  add_action(
     'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', function() {

    if ($total < 1)) {
        return;
    }

    else{
    printf(
        '<h2 class="mk-wc-title">%s<small class="mk-wc-subtitle">%s</small></h2>',
        esc_html__( 'Choose your payment method', 'mk_framework' ),
        esc_html__( 'Enter your payment details.', 'mk_framework' )
    );}

} 
);
```

I can use all the help!

Orginal code

```
// Add title and subtitle for payment form.
  add_action(
             'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', function() 
            {

if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        return;
    }

        printf(
            '<h2 class="mk-wc-title">%s<small class="mk-wc-subtitle">%s</small></h2>',
            esc_html__( 'Choose your payment method', 'mk_framework' ),
            esc_html__( 'Enter your payment details.', 'mk_framework' )
        );

}
```

);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  add_action(
             'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', function() 
            {
             $amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );

            if ($total < 1)) 
            {
                return;
            }

            else{
            printf(
                '<h2 class="mk-wc-title">%s<small class="mk-wc-subtitle">%s</small></h2>',
                esc_html__( 'Choose your payment method', 'mk_framework' ),
                esc_html__( 'Enter your payment details.', 'mk_framework' )
            );}

        }
```

Comment: Thank u for the comment, My website crashes with this code :(

Comment: Now you can check

Comment: What did you change?, If I copy again. still crash

Comment: I changed it in the checkout.php

Comment: Does it overide the code from the checkout.php? see original code please

Comment: @MilanG I am working locally. But I am curious if about this "Does it overide the code from the checkout.php? see original code please"

Comment: If I put this code in checkout.php I get message " Website have technical problems", and If I put it in functions.php, nothing happends

Comment: Still no, Can we try something like (for functions.php)

if total is less than 1
hide 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment'

Because it is already a action in checkout.php

Comment: yes you can but for that you need to add  WC()->cart->get_total()